Traducción al español de "sweep"
Una de las acepciones del verbo "sweep" en inglés es:

affect (an area or place) swiftly and widely.

¿Hay alguna palabra en español que tenga el mismo significado, o al menos uno parecido? Estuve contemplando extenderse, pero no me convence.
Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Cita? No encontré esa definición en ningún lado, me parece que sweep significa otra cosa

Mejor considerar ejemplos concretos. Como se ve en las respuestas, para cada combinación de la causa que afecta y a quién o a qué afecta puede haber una palabra diferente.

Una palabra en español que podría tener un significado similar es “arrasar”.
Esta palabra se usa para describir cuando algo afecta o destruye un área de manera rápida y extensa.
Por ejemplo, podrías decir “El huracán arrasó la costa”.

"arrasar" tal vez sea la mejor palabra, porque combina los dos conceptos: afectar/azotar + extenderse sobre un área

Parece que tu extracto forma parte de la segunda acepción de sweep que podemos encontrar aquí


[intr.] move swiftly and smoothly: a large black car swept past the open windows | fig. a wave of sympathy swept over him. ∎  [tr.] cause
to move swiftly and smoothly: he swept his hand around the room. ∎
(of a person) move in a confident and stately manner: she swept
magnificently from the hall. ∎  (of a geographical or natural feature)
extend continuously in a particular direction, esp. in a curve: green
forests swept down the hillsides. ∎  [tr.] look swiftly over: her eyes
swept the room. ∎  affect (an area or place) swiftly and widely:
violence swept the country | [intr.] the rebellion had swept through
all four of the country's provinces. ∎  [tr.] win all the games in (a
series); take each of the winning or main places in (a contest or
event): we knew we had to sweep these three home games.


Dados los ejemplos que aparecen ahí para esa acepción

Violence swept the countryThe rebellion had swept through all four of
the country's provinces

Para la primera frase yo emplearía el verbo desencadenar en su cuarta acepción


tr. Originar, provocar o dar salida a movimientos del ánimo, hechos o series de hechos, generalmente apasionados o violentos.


Con lo cual tendríamos

La violencia se desencadenó por todo el país

Aquí también podríamos emplear asolar en su primera acepción


tr. Destruir, arruinar, arrasar.


Con lo cual tendríamos

La violencia asoló el país

Como sinónimo de asolar/destruir/arrasar tenemos también barrer, que se puede emplear como traducción de sweep en alguna de sus otras acepciones, con lo cual mantendríamos ese relación

La violencia barrió el país

Para la segunda frase yo emplearía "extender rápidamente", ya que se hace mención detallada de la superficie que abarcó la rebelión. Hay que tener en cuenta que el verbo extender no conlleva implícitamente esa rapidez (swift) con lo cual tendríamos que añadirla.
La frase en español quedaría

La rebelión se había extendido rápidamente por las cuatro provincias del país

La rebelión se había extendido rápidamente por todas las provincias del país

"Todas las cuatro provincias" no acaba de sonarme idiomático en español, pero supongo que podrías ponerlo también.
Y para cerrar el círculo en ambas sentencias podemos emplear la locución adverbial "correr como la pólvora", que significa "extenderse rápidamente".


La violencia corrió como la pólvora por el país
La rebelión había corrido como la pólvora por las cuatro provincias del país

En cualquier caso, tu pregunta es demasiado genérica. Sería interesante que aportaras algo más de contexto para que se te ofrezca una traducción más ajustada a un frase específica.
